# How to use NSWindowController to show a window in standard application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nib, nswindowcontroller

I created a new blank standard application using Xcode template. Removed the window in MainMenu.xib and I created a new customized NSWindowController subclass with a xib.

They were named "WYSunFlowerWindowController.h" and "WYSunFlowerWindowController.m".

And I append then init function like below:

```
- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"init()");

    return [super initWithWindowNibName:@"WYSunFlowerWindowController" owner:self];
}
```

And my WYAppDelegate.m file is like below:

```
static WYSunFlowerMainWindowController* windowController = nil;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    if (windowController == nil) {
        windowController = [[WYSunFlowerMainWindowController alloc] init];
    }
    [[windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:windowController];
}
```

And I have the problem, that the window can't show it self after I launch the app. Anyone can tell me why? Is anything wrong with my code?

I am a newbie in Objective-C and cocoa. So I think I maybe make a silly mistake that I can't figure it out by myself.

UPDATE:

Here is my project source. Pleas have a look and help me to figure out what is my mistake。

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3193707/SunFlower.zip

Comment: Do you have ARC enabled? I've found that with ARC the window controller gets deallocated unless I make it a property of the App Delegate (I am sure there are other ways to do this).

Comment: I am using ARC. I make the windowController as a static field of the AppDelegate Class. I think it won't be deallocated until app is terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your init method, I think you have to set self to the super init first before you return self.

```
-(id)init
{
    NSLog (@"init()");
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"WYSunFlowerWindowController" owners:self];
    return self;
}
```

**Edit**:

Try replace `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` with `[windowController showWindow:self]`

Then if that still doesn't work, check your window controller xib, make sure the file owner is set to WYSunFlowerWindowController and that the IBOutlet Window (declared in NSWindowController) is connected to the window.

**Edit 2:**

Commenting out your @property and @synthesize window in your controller was the trick.  Don't redeclare get and setters that were already predefined in a superclass.

Comment: thank you for your help. I followed your instruction and nothing changed. Still not work.

Comment: I have done all you mentioned. Not work. I you don't mind can you download my project source to have a look? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3193707/SunFlower.zip

Comment: Oh my god, it works! Thank you so much. But I am confused that why a window outlet property defined in subclass will cause this problem? Can't they override the same property of the class's parent?

Comment: The problem isn't that you're overriding the instance variable, but you're overriding the getter/setter.  NSWindowController probably does something to it whenever you set the window ivar, and thus why nothing shows up if you override it.   Just remember to not redeclare ivars, as it does nothing at all, and could be potentially dangerous.